# Как в патерн для re.findall засунуть значение переменной

Tags: python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Дана строка, в которой нужно найти предложение или слово начало и конец которых обозначенны маркерами которые в свою очередь тоже известны.
например в строке-'What is >apple<' или 'What is >an apple<' вытащить слова отмеченные маркерами"><"
Вот мой код:

```
    import re

    def between_markers(text: str, begin: str, end: str) -> str:
        stack = re.findall(r'[\begin\]\w+[\end\]', text)

    return stack
```

Как в патерн-r'[]' написать аргумент функции чтобы этот аргумент опознался?
Ну или как найти слова или слово между двуми данными аргументами функции, с помощью библиотеки re?

Comment: fr'[\\{begin}\\]\w+[\\{end}\\]'

Answer (score 0):

Как ни странно, но я сам нашёл ответ на саму задачу, а не на вопрос.

```
return text[text.index(begin)+1:text.index(end)]
```

Эта строчка решает всю задачу, но мне всё-таки интересно, как в паттерны вписать переменные?

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом вернем углу страницы. если надо указать контекст, можете привести ссылку на данный вопрос.